# How can I read binary file in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read binary file in **tensorflow**.
I want to ask, which method should I use, and how for reading binary file.
In tensorflow, they recommends use dataset in tf.data.
But I can't find simple example of using dataset, especially FixedLengthRecordDataset. I think I should use this method, but I don't know how to use.

```
[hg file] := [file header] [image1] [image2] [image3] ...

[file header] := "hg  " (8 bytes)

[imageN] := [image header] [image data]

[image header] := [code(2 bytes)] [width (1 byte)] [height(1 byte)] [reserved(2 bytes)]

[image data] := 256 gray data (width * height bytes, row-major format)
```

This is the format of my binary file.

Please give me some advice for this work.

EDIT : All images have different size. So maybe I can't use FixedLengthRecordDatasest. I think I have to convert all images to same size of dataset

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd need to write your own Dataset reader op to parse that format. [FixedLengthRecordDataset's implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/acb1ef68f5aea3b6f7f1e14db588b74134719b5e/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/reader_dataset_ops.cc#L265) would be a good place to start for structuring the code (but as you note, the records you've described are not fixed length).

I would recommend instead re-encoding the images in `tf.train.Example` protocol buffers, then [using a `TFRecordDataset` for input](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#parsing_tfexample_protocol_buffer_messages). That way the parsing is already written for you; you should be able to create `tf.train.Example` protos in any language.